# Embedded Tomcat instance does not see APR Library

Tags: tomcat, ssl, apr

I am currently trying - without success - to use the APR lib within embedded Tomcat for the purposes of SSL.

I tried a number of ways to ensure the library gets loaded - setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, setting -Djava.library.path, and loading the libtcnative-1.so directly in the code - but always get this message when the APR SSL connector is referenced:

```
The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available.
```

When I run non-embedded Tomcat the APR lib is picked up without any problem.

My question is: Is there an inherent problem with using APR/SSL within embedded Tomcat?

Note:  The environment is CentOS 6.3 and Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: Have you enabled the `APRLifecycleListener` in your embedded configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable the `APRLifecycleListener` in your embedded code in order to actually load the native library. You could also just load the library yourself, but the APRLifecycleListener will give you come nice information about the native support when you load it.

Comment: This solved an issue for me where I want to add APR to a production VPS with tomcat 8.0.14 and I used a virtual machine with tomcat 8.5.14 to test. It worked on the virtual machine but not on the VPS because the line that enables `APRLifecycleListener` in `server.xml` is enabled by default in 8.5.14 but not in 8.0.14. Except I've got other differences to iron out now...